# Get values of specific property of array elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following question on Javascript 
Suppose we have 
srcArr -  array of objects , each defined as following

```
var srcElement = {id:id_val , prop1:value1, prop2:value2}
```

I need to  get array of id-s of array elements.I.e. array of elements like {id;:id_val}
The simplest way is something like this

```
var arrayLength = srcArr.length;
for (var index=0; index<arrayLength;index++) {
  idsArr.push(srcArr[index].id);     
}
```

The question is  : Is there more effective way to get ids of array elements?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can try [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, but `for` is fastest

Comment: If you don't have a problem, then it seems the question is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Btw, how do you define "more effective"? Doesn't the code do what you want?

Comment: I meant : is this native implementation (with for loop) the fastest ?

Answer (score 2):

A common re-usable functional approach:

```
var collec = [
  {num:1, str:'a'},
  {num:2, str:'b'}
];

var dot = function(prop) {
  return function(obj) {
    return obj[prop];
  }
};

collec.map(dot('num')); //=> [1,2]
collec.map(dot('str')); //=> ['a','b']
```

Answer (score 1):

using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)'s map function

```
srcArr = [{id:1}, {id:2}]
var result = _.map(srcArr, function(el){
    return el.id
});
//result = [1,2]
```

map will perform the same function on each element and add the result to a new array

EDIT:
this is not as fast as a native for loop.

http://jsperf.com/javascript-map-vs-jquery-map-vs-jquery-each

Comment: why you think that is more effective?

Comment: underscore `map` use native `map` if it possible

Comment: map is a common pattern that defines exatly what we want to do: map one array to another

Comment: so why not use native implementation?

Comment: native array.map is added in ECMA5 so wont work in old browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: The question is to know whether native implementation ( with for loop) is fastest

Comment: map is actually slower than a native for loop, however I believe it's more maintainable/better style http://jsperf.com/javascript-map-vs-jquery-map-vs-jquery-each

Answer (score 1):

The `map` method can be used as an iterator, but is really meant to manipulate the supplied array and return a new array.

So at the end:

**`For loop map` is much more faster than `Jquery map`. [Test the performance of the same here](http://jsperf.com/map-vs-native-for-loop)**

Here you go:

```
var srcArray = [{
    id: 1,
    prop1: 'a',
    prop2: 'b'
}, {
    id: 2,
    prop1: 'c',
    prop2: 'd'
}];
map = function (array, mapFunction) {
    var newArray = new Array(array.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = mapFunction(array[i]);
    }

    return newArray;
}
var newItems = map(srcArray, function (i) {
    return i.id;
});
```

Output

```
newItems: [1,2]
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9AfNJ/1/)

### [image]

Answer (score 0):

If effective means short and readable, you could use the Lodash `pluck` function :

```
var idsArr = _.pluck(srcArr, 'id');
```

http://lodash.com/docs#pluck

Here is the souce code : https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L3848. I suspect it to be slower than a good old for loop but you should run some performance tests if you actually care about that : [google "jsperf map"](https://www.google.fr/search?q=jsperf%20map).

That said, it's quite easy to write your own pluck function :

```
function pluck(src, key) {
    var i = 0, l = src.length, result = [];
    while (i < l) result.push(src[i++][key]);
    return result;
}
```